# Can i tell if i am being observed by an admin using apple remote desktop?

Tags: apple-remote-desktop

Is there a way i can tell if i am being observed by an admin who is using apple remote desktop (ARD) ?

Is there an icon that will pop up in the dock / top bar ? Or is there a port I could check to see if there is traffic passing through it ?

Comment: I wanted to put this in a comment, but [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58826) may help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For someone to be able to observe you using Apple Remote Desktop, Remote Management needs to be enabled in the Sharing Preferences, on your computer.

[image]

Clicking on the Computer Settings opens a window to enable options for showing the icon in the status menu when someone is connected to you.

[image]